# How to use MacBook (Pro) as KVM console for one or more computers with minimal additional hardware?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb, thunderbolt

The goal is to use some kind of software on a MacBook in order for it to emulate a keyboard, mouse, and display, acting as a KVM (keyboard, video, mouse) console able to switch control between itself and at least one attached computer.

The connection to the other computer should be nothing more than a USB-C Thunderbolt cable, or a USB-C/male to USB-A/male cable like that used to connect a USB-C phone to a computer except that in this case the MacBook is the "peripheral" rather than a phone.

The intended users would be people that have a MacBook as their personal computer and a computer that is locked up tight from their school or employer.  The MacBook must emulate USB and/or Thunderbolt devices as there is no knowing if it would be allowed to perform BlueTooth pairing, some kind of network control (VNC or RDP as common examples), or any configuration changes or software installs.  While the computer attached to the MacBook is most likely a functional Windows computer of some type the intent is to have a MacBook act as a KVM console for the purpose of diagnosing a non-booting system, if the MacBook doesn't emulate USB then boot firmware is not likely to function with it.

The hardware required between the two computers should be no more complicated than a USB or Thunderbolt cable since this should be something that can be implemented easily and on short notice.  If the solution requires purchase of some hardware that can't be found at a grocery store or truck stop then the cost and/or delay just leaves the user getting a traditional KVM switch, a video capture device and other bits and bobs, or doing without.

The solution does not strictly have to run in MacOS so long as there is a means to run MacOS on the MacBook somehow still.  One thing that comes to mind is loading some version of Linux to run "USB gadgets" software to emulate the USB devices and then run MacOS in a virtual machine.  This could get out of the realm of a quick and easy install but it at least avoids added hardware that may be difficult to find, could be lost or broken, or again get us back to finding readily known hardware solutions at lower costs.

The software solution sought does not have to be free but it does need to be something that can be downloaded on short notice and/or a copy kept on a drive somewhere, and not cost so much that hardware solutions look tame by comparison.  Again, if there is hardware beyond a common peripheral cable then it could be easily damaged or lost but people tend to keep their MacBook safe.

Apple MacBooks can emulate USB and Thunderbolt devices for target disk mode to work so the hardware to make this work is inside the computer.  I suspect other brands of laptops have this feature but I'd like to keep this to Apple hardware for now.

I recognize that a computer pretending to be a Thunderbolt display is not a common request, and support for Thunderbolt displays is not common in computers either, this is why I ask the question here as there's a lot of noise from internet searches making it difficult to find a useful signal.  Perhaps some guidance on good search terms to use is all I need.

If there's no software to get a MacBook to emulate a display then it would still be useful for a MacBook to emulate USB keyboard and mouse as that means more easily sharing the limited physical space on a desk or table with two computers as well as using a MacBook as part of a portable KVM console, the video being handled by a video capture peripheral or a separate display.  If the MacBook could emulate other USB or Thunderbolt devices then that would be even more useful.  The MacBook appearing as a drive, network adapter, or audio I/O device, are examples of what would be useful.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use VNC/RDP over Ethernet/Wifi?

Comment: Also, right now your question is rather long-winded and it's not so easy to understand what you are actually looking for and what the constraints are. It also seems to lack any indication of research done already. Can you please edit it make it more focussed?

Comment: I was in the middle of answering this when it closed? - It is a long question, but it is very specific so quite easy to answer?

Comment: @nohillside  Yes, there is a specific reason I can't use VNC/RDP.  That was in the question I posted.  The computer is locked down by the owner of the computer, a school or employer, which means no adding software or enabling any built-in remote desktop service.

Comment: @nohillside  I realize my question is on the long side, the length was an attempt to be as specific as I could on the constraints.  Can you be more specific on where you are confused?

Comment: @jksoegaard reopened. Maybe I‘m the only one confused here, looking forward to your answer.

Comment: In short: you're asking how to do something that the 'school or employer' does not want you to do to their equipment.

Comment: @benwiggy He's actually asking the exact opposite of that. He's asking how to do this WITHOUT doing what the school or employer has stated he is not allowed to do.

Comment: The computer owner will not and cannot prevent attachment of a keyboard, mouse, and display by the user as doing so renders the computer useless.  If some other computer emulates a USB keyboard, USB mouse, and Thunderbolt display then this computer is no different than a KVM switch and/or KVM console.  There is no intent to circumvent the wishes of the computer owner, rather a means to offer the owner a software alternative to what might otherwise be a greater expense in hardware.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** As far as I know, no such complete solution, working as you described, exist for the MacBook Pro or indeed any other type of laptop from other vendors.

---

For those interested in details about why such a solution most likely doesn't exist, and maybe looking for alternatives, let me explain a bit more:

Your hand waving argument that Target Disk Mode exists and this must mean that the hardware to perform this task is already "inside the computer", I believe to be false. The hardware to perform the task of emulating a display and capturing the video data is simply not there.

If you look only at the task of emulating a USB device - then yes, that is relatively easy and many solutions already exist for this purpose. For example making it possible for a computer to present itself over USB as a peripheral (instead of as a host) - and emulating a mass storage device, keyboard, mouse or similar.

A very easy way to do that is by running Linux on the MacBook Pro and configuring what they call "USB gadgets" (their term for "emulating" a USB device). For example that could be the [g_mass_storage](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/mass-storage.txt) driver to emulate a mass storage device or the [g_hid](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_hid.txt) driver to emulate a keyboard and/or mouse. Many other drivers exist - for example g_ether and g_cdc for emulating network adapters, g_webcam for emulating webcams and so on.

If you want to do this from macOS, it is entirely possible as well - but it is not as readily available as on Linux. For example you can take inspiration from the [foohid](https://github.com/unbit/foohid) driver to emulate keyboard and/or mouse - but it will require you to program yourself.

Similarly you can do it with other operating systems such as for example FreeBSD - there it is quite simply configured using a sysctl named [`hw.usb.template`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=usb_template&sektion=4&format=html), however it is a bit limited in configuration options.

Note that there's no gadget driver for emulating a display, as that is not possible!

Remember that emulating USB devices requires the computer used as the KVM console to have the needed hardware as well. I.e. you need either USB-C, a USB OTG port or a dedicated USB device port (i.e. typically a micro-B connector).

A practical solution to your problem will require adding some hardware. You could for example use a USB-connected video capture device to access display signal from the other computer (i.e. for example the computer to be controlled outputs HDMI, and you use a USB-C HDMI capture device). These devices are available at a relatively low price today - i.e. starting at something like 30$ depending on where in the world you're located. Note that the devices vary in capability such as frames per second, maximum resolution, etc.

Another option is to simply buy dedicated KVM hardware. There are many large vendors (Raritan, BlackBox, etc.) that have dedicated KVM-over-IP hardware available - these are usually handy when you have a large number of devices to manage, such as for example a rack of servers.

Today some smaller scale solutions intended for home usage also exist. For example the [TinyPilot](https://tinypilotkvm.com) device, which is a ready to use device based on the Raspberry Pi. It costs $360, so it is not exactly a cheap device - but if you only need to manage a single computer, and you perhaps have other uses for it - it could be worth it. If you have multiple devices, this will end up being much more expensive than the previously mentioned KVM hardware. Also note that latency is usually a bit higher with this type of device.

There's also the option of building such a device yourself. There exists an open source project called [PiKVM](https://pikvm.org) with software, building instructions, etc. that you can try out. If you have some of the kit in advance (for example an Raspberry Pi), it might end up being a cheap way of getting it to work. You can also buy a pre-assembled version for $250.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139974/discussion-between-macguffin-and-jksoegaard).